# Html link parametrs for download

Tags: html, download, hyperlink

I want to include link to download file in my html-page like this

`<a href="file_folder/myfile.exe">MyFile</a>`

but when I click to my link I can see binary code of my file in browser instead redirect to download file. How I can fix it without change settings of my web-server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The only way is to change the sent MIME type on the web server. `application/octet-stream` would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but there is a way to do this now (see the [download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download)):

```
<a href="hugepdf.pdf" download>Download file</a>
```

As explained by [Jonathan Svärdén](http://svarden.se/blog/2013-04-22-right-click-and-save-as/).